# hibernate initiate correctly OneToOne object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the next situation. I have POJO class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="project")
    public class Project {

        public Donation donation;

        public Project() {}
        public Project(int param1, int param2 ...) {
            ...//other field initialisied
            donation = new Donation(param1, param2);
        }

        //methods

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "donation_project_id")
        public Donation getDonation() {
            return donation;
        }
    }

        public void setDonation(Donation donation) {
            this.donation = donation;
        }
    }
```

**Donation** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="donation")
public class Donation {

        public Donation() {}

        public DonationLogic(int param1, int param2) {
            //initialisation
        }
        //other methods
}
```

*Project* table/class relays some parameters to another table/class *Donation*. Two classes are Entities. And I use Spring+Hibernate. My question is if I correctly initiate class *Donation* which is created in constructor of *Project* class? I think using **new** operator inside Spring smells bad. Maybe there is another way to do this task? - create class/table that is filled from another table/class. Maybe separate parameters for two classes and not use one constructor to initiate to classes? But use setters of Donation class? However if I have many parameters, many setters I will need to use((( Hmm((

Comment: hibernate requires a no-argument constructor for all persistent classes

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I forgot defualt constructor. But you didnt understand my question. Edited question.

Answer (score 0):

> I think using new operator inside Spring smells bad.

Not really. But, anyway, you shouldn't use `new` in `@Entity` class and whole model layer. Instead of that you should move `new` to service layer, because now it looks like business logic is in your entity class.

Returning to your question: you should better reconsider your app architecture. As I said, `new` operator shouldn't be used inside model layer and `@Entity` classes. You are creating new bean, so it looks like some logic action. So move this action to `@Service` class and use `@Repository` as DAO to access basic operations on persistence objects. Your DAO will support and handle `@OneToOne` annotation without writing `new` in your entity beans.

Helpful link: [Effective pattern for data access with JPA](http://workingonbits.com/2011/05/05/effective-pattern-for-data-access-with-jpa/)